# bash check a file doesnt exist using variable from array

Tags: arrays, bash, file

I have an array of file names, I want to select one and then check that it doesn't currently exist on the system in a particular directory, this is my code snippet:

```
if [ ! -f /usr/local/nginx/conf/conf.d/${cdarray[choice]}.conf ]; then
  echo "File not found!"
fi
```

However this isn't quite right

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you explain why you believe it's not quite right? For example, can you show the output of `echo "Checking for file /usr/local/nginx/conf/conf.d/${cdarray[choice]}.conf"` along with an `ls -l /thatpath` showing that the file does in fact exist?

Comment: Hi if I just echo /usr/local/nginx/conf/conf.d/${cdarray[choice]}.conf it correctly inserts the file name it should do, and in my system the file does not exist, however when I test for it using the above code, It does not print the statement 'file not found' so I the test is not working even though the file doesnt exist

Comment: Just realised it is working correctly, it is me thats conflated 2 directories together in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Export the variable prior to calling test and then check for the existence of the file. .